# In PLSQL, how to loop though results from a select and then output contents (clob) to a file and update a status

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

I have a select statement that will will return a number of keys:

```
select key_val from X where a=b;
```

Then I need to use key_val to interrogate the table and output the contents to a file.

```
select clob_col from X where x.key_val = 'value of previous statement'
```

presumably using dbms_output.put_line(value of a cursor)

then I need to update the status on the table

```
update x set status = 'XXX' where x.key_val = 'value of previous statement'
```

Then loop though for all key_val's returned from the first statement.

I've not much experience in PLSQL which is what the script needs to be written in, I understand the concept of while loops etc as I could write this in a shell script but wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction of how to achieve in PLSQL

Comment: You can loop around cursor results with a [cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html). You can write to a file on the server with [utl_file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_FILE.html). I'd suggest using a stored procedure rather than a script. (Most of the examples in the documentation are written in block caps for some reason but you don't have to do that.) Give it a try and update the question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

As you're going to use PL/SQL, `UTL_FILE` package is what you need. As it creates a file on a database server, you'll first have to create a **directory** (an Oracle object which points to a filesystem directory) and grant some privileges to user (`scott` in my example) who will be using it (the directory).

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as `scott`.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
```

Sample tables: `x` contains keys, `test_clob` contains actual values.

```
SQL> select * From x;

        ID    KEY_VAL STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
       100          1
       200          2           

SQL> desc test_clob
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 KEY_VAL                                            NUMBER
 COL                                                CLOB

SQL> select * from test_clob;

   KEY_VAL COL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 Littlefoot
         2 Bigfoot

SQL>
```

PL/SQL procedure accept `x` table's ID and exports `CLOB` column from `test_clob` table whose `key_val` corresponds to `x.key_val`.

First, check directories available to me:

```
SQL> select * from all_directories;

OWNER      DIRECTORY_NAME       DIRECTORY_PATH
---------- -------------------- --------------------
SYS        EXT_DIR              c:\temp

SQL>
```

OK, only one; that's enough.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_export_clob (par_id in x.id%type)
  2  is
  3    l_file    utl_file.file_type;
  4    l_buffer  varchar2(32767);
  5    l_amount  binary_integer := 32767;
  6    l_pos     integer := 1;
  7  begin
  8    update x set status = 'xxx' where id = par_id;
  9
 10    for cur_c in (select c.col
 11                  from test_clob c join x on x.key_val = c.key_val
 12                  where x.id = par_id
 13                 )
 14    loop
 15      l_file := utl_file.fopen('EXT_DIR', 'test_clob.txt', 'w', 32767);
 16
 17      loop
 18        dbms_lob.read (cur_c.col, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
 19        utl_file.put(l_file, l_buffer);
 20        utl_file.fflush(l_file);
 21        l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
 22      end loop;
 23    end loop;
 24  exception
 25    when no_data_found then
 26      utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 27    when others then
 28      utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 29      raise;
 30  end;
 31  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_export_clob (100);      --> should export "Littlefoot"
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From x;

        ID    KEY_VAL STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
       100          1 xxx
       200          2

SQL>
```

[image]